# PostgreSQL version incompability

Tags: postgresql

The situation is the following:

I have install the postgresql-9.3 with command

```
    sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3:
```

and then use pg_ctl to start the server

```
    pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main -Z coordinator start
```

which causes following error:

```
    18:23:50 CEST FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server 2014-07-14 18:23:50 CEST DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 9.3, which is not compatible with this version 9.2.4.
```

I have no idea where comes the version 9.2.4, I have checked all my folders about Postgres, they all under folder 9.3 and even tried `pg_clusters`. Can anyone give some hints to fix this?

`dpkg -l | grep` postgres gives the result:

```
ii  postgres-xc               1.1-2ubuntu2  amd64        write-scalable, synchronous multi-master, transparent PostgreSQL cluster
ii  postgres-xc-client        1.1-2ubuntu2  amd64        front-end programs for Postgres-XC
rc  postgresql-9.3            9.3.4-1       amd64        object-relational SQL database, version 9.3 server
rc  postgresql-client-common  154           all          manager for multiple PostgreSQL client versions
rc  postgresql-common         154           all          PostgreSQL database-cluster manager
```

I have tried once to delete "everything", and reinstall them again
now I have the output of dpkg -l | grep` postgres:

```
    ii  postgresql-9.3        9.3.4-1       amd64        object-relational SQL database, version 9.3 server
    ii  postgresql-client-9.3 9.3.4-1       amd64        front-end programs for PostgreSQL 9.3
    ii  postgresql-client-common  154       all          manager for multiple PostgreSQL client versions
    ii  postgresql-common         154       all          PostgreSQL database-cluster manager
```

now everything looks fine, when I try to start the server with pg_ctl the command line tells me:

```
    The program 'pg_ctl' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
```

sudo apt-get install postgres-xc

Is there any other way to start the server? Should I install postgres-xc following the advise?

Thank you

Comment: Looks like you have installed multiple versions of Postgres on your system. You neglected to mention your OS, looks like Ubuntu or Debian. Also post what you get for `dpkg -l | grep postgres`.

Comment: Can you execute `which pg_ctl` in shell and check if you are using correct verion of installed postgres?

Comment: `pg_ctl` does not support a parameter `-Z`. It seems you are mixing your Postgres-XC and and PostgreSQL installs.

Comment: thank you for your answer @Igor Romanchenko, which pg_ctl gives me /usr/bin/pg_ctl. What can I use them for diagnose ?

Comment: Use `pg_ctl --version` to make sure you're running the right `pg_ctl`

Comment: @Craig Ringer, you are right. It seems that my pg_ctl is version 9.2.4

Answer (score 1):

There is an old Postgres 9.2 installation on your machine (unless you are not confusing two machines). Assuming Debian for lack of information. Ubuntu should be similar.

Check with

```
dpkg -l | grep postgres
```

(Unless you are installing programs without the package manager as well, then you should also be able to untangle this mess.)

If you don't need Postgres 9.2 any more (make sure of that!) uninstall it. Then everything should work just fine.

```
sudo apt-get remove postgresql-9.2
```

Or even:

```
sudo apt-get purge postgresql-9.2
```

If you want to keep both (or more) versions in parallel, I suggest you install `postgresql-common` and `postgresql-client-common` additionally, which helps to make this possible.

Comment: Hi Erwin, Thank you for your answer @Erwin Brandstetter. They are really just in the right direction, but there aren't any other version of ubuntu installed on my machine. The remove and purge command gives me following information 'Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-9.2
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-9.2''

Comment: After your added information, the question is: Why did you install [Postgres-XC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/postgres-xc/) in the first place and can you remove it? Again, be *sure* of it. If not needed, you can remove it with above commands. Replace `postgres-9.2` with `postgres-xc`.

Comment: Hello @Erwin Brandstetter, thank you for you answer again. I have removed poostgres-xc. Now I can not use pg_ctl, that is also the reason why I install it. Should I remove postgres-xc-client also?

Comment: I have also removed postgres-xc-client. @Erwin Brandstetter